# Enter Insert/Edit mode of CLion IDE

Tags: clion

New to CLion, not sure if its just me, but everytime I type, the "Search for" bar appears in the Project directory left side bar. I am unable to type anything into the opened file. The caret does not even appear on the file. It's like when using Vim, but you're not in Insert mode. I have no idea how to go and start typing into the IDE. Any recommendations to how to use this thing?

Answer (score 0):

It it because the focus in on the Project pane:

[image]

Just click once in the editor pane (where the file you want to edit is displayed). The caret will appear and you will be able to type.

[image]

Comment: My editor (2016.1) definitely does not allow me to do that. Clicking the editor does not return the caret to the file.

Comment: @lzc I use 2016.1 too (and all the previous ones). The behavior you describe is very strange indeed. Did you try the last resort of reinstalling?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's painful, but just restart the IDE. That's what I did and it works now.